# Users interfering with each others instances

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

In my multiple choice Quiz show project on google app engine multiple users can use the webapp simultaneously once they are login. But due to some reason they are interfering with each others instances.
Scenario example: Suppose user A wants to use the quiz show for 10 questions and at the same time user B wants to run the quiz show for 10 questions on another machine. But since they are using the application at the same, they are only getting 5 questions each and their result getting messed up.
Does anybody know how to avoid it ? I am not using any session or cookies till now. Is that a solution or something else?
Thanks

```
#views.py
```

def display(request):
    skipped_questions=[]
    question_number=[]
    user_answer_list=[]
    answer_list=[]
    all_questions=[]
    if request.method=='POST':
        initial_value=1
        id_list=[]
        result=Questions.objects.all()
        for i in result:
            id_value=i.id
            id_list.append(id_value)

```
    data=request.POST.copy()
    total_question=data['number_of_question']
    mytime=data['time']
    seconds=59
    minutes=int(mytime)-1
    already_questions=Random_model.objects.all().delete()
    already_answers=User_answer.objects.all().delete()
    random_questions_list=random.sample(id_list,int(total_question))
    for i in random_questions_list:
        random_model=Random_model()
        random_model.list_id=i
        random_model.initial_value=int(initial_value)
        random_model.save()
        initial_value+=1
    question_list=1
    a=Random_model.objects.get(initial_value=question_list)
    new_question=Questions.objects.get(id=a.list_id)
    template_value={ 'output': new_question,'minutes':minutes,'seconds':seconds,'question_list':question_list }
    return render_to_response("quiz.html",template_value)
```

Followup-@Adam:Hi,I have removed global variables and again the program is working fine when I am working alone on my laptop. But when I am asking my colleague to try from his end,we both are getting same questions and interfering in each others sessions due to which end output getting messed up. I started using gae-sessions and able to use request.session but how should I use gae-sessions in this scenario.
Let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: It's hard to approach this without some more clues.  What does the view look like?  Any other code that you think is relevant?

Comment: Remember that requests to an AppEngine application are still just HTTP requests and are thus stateless. You are going to have to do something to distinguish one request from another.

Comment: @Justin Myles Holmes:Thanks Justin for your reply. Actually the problem is once different users are login with their username, they are not getting their different sessions or instances. So if two different users are doing something on the project,they are actually not having their seperate instances but due to some reason their work is getting mixed. Let me know if I am still not clear.

Comment: Are you using sessions for this purpose?  I really feel like I need to see the relevant code from the view.

Comment: @Adam Crossland: Yes,very true.I think that is the case. But I don't know how to implement it in my project.

Comment: You say you don't use sessions or cookies, but you also say that your users are logging in.  How do you know who is logged in?  Either you aren't really logging them in, or you are using some kind of session / cookie to track this.

Comment: @Peter Recore: I am using django.contrib.auth for login and logout the users. Apologies if its internally creates sessions. I am not aware about it.

Comment: @Justin Myles Holmes:Their is not any specific code I have written in my view to avoid this problem since I was not sure this might be happen. Also I have not used sessions in my view only using django.contrib.auth to login purpose.Let me know if you still want to see the code since its big file.

Comment: Show us how you associate questions with users!

Comment: @Justin Myles Holmes:I have pasted my relevent view code. Please note that I am using global variables so that I can implement static behavior of variable to make other functions to access the value.

Comment: Merciful code Jesus! So many globals!

Comment: I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @Adam Crossland:First project so forgive. With experience may become good :-)

Comment: @SRC: using globals is *the wrong way to accomplish what you want to do.* You should take all of those globels and store to equivalent data in a dictionary. The dictionary is then passed around between all functions that need to access that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some concrete details about what kind of data your application stores to make one session different from any other, it is impossible to give you anything really useful, but one approach would be to store it in memcache keyed off of the user's user_id.

Completely hypothetical for-example code:

```
def get_session_data():
    from google.appengine.api import users

    found_session = None

    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        from google.appengine.api import memcache

        users_session = memcache.get(user.user_id())


    return found_session

def save_session_data(session_object):
    from google.appengine.api import users
    from google.appengine.api import memcache

    memcache.set(users.get_current_user().user_id(), serialized_object)
```

Now, before you go cutting and pasting, there are a lot of caveats to this approach, and it is meant only as a suggested starting point. Memcache is not guaranteed to hold items in memory, and there are plenty of other competing implementations that would be more reliable in some respects.

**Fundamentally, I'd suggest using cookies to store the session data, but AppEngine doesn't have native support for cookies, so you'd have to go find an implementation of them and include it in your code. There are a number of fine implementations that are available on Google Code.**

Here are some libraries to pick from that provide cookie support. There are even more.

[gae-utilities](http://gaeutilities.appspot.com/)

[gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki)

[app-engine-oil](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-oil/)

FOLLOWUP, based on the sample code that you just added:
I don't want to put too fine of a point on it, but what you're doing *just ain't gonna work.*

Using global variables is generally a bad idea, but it is specifically an unworkable idea in a piece of code that is going to be called by many different users in an overlapping-fashion. The best advice that I can give you is to take all of the painful global variables (which are really specific to a particular user), and store them in a dictionary that is specific to a particular user. The pickling/unpickling code that I posted above is a workable approach, but seriously, ***until you get rid of those globals, your code isn't going to work.***

Comment: @Adam Crossland:First of all thank you and apologies for not accurately defining the problem.Learning Django and GAE from last month so a bit new :-) I will check pickle and cookies more for django-nonrel since I am using that.

Comment: @Adam Crossland:Thanks.will correct the code as per your suggestion and update you soon.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest using an existing sessions library, rather than using memcache - or at least use the datastore.

Comment: App Engine's memcache implementation will actually do the pickling for you if you pass it an pickleable object rather than a string, so this can be simplified a bit.

Comment: Excellent point, @Wooble. I updated the code to reflect. Also, in agreement with @Nick's comment, I bolded the section where I suggest that cookies is the best approach.

Comment: @Adam:Forgot to close the issue.After some efforts GAE-sessions done the trick.Thank you for your time!!